# Unminified production build of Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

As far as I know, the minified production build offered on [emberjs.com](http://www.emberjs.com/) is not only minified but also modified (less assertions).

Now I'm asking myself if I can grab an *unminified* production build somewhere. Anybody?

Comment: http://emberjs.com/builds/#/release/latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the most recent build, from the master branch https://s3.amazonaws.com/builds.emberjs.com/ember-latest.js. Unminified and with all the assertions.

Comment: Nope. *(this must be one of the reasons why SO discourages "questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource (...)" to begin with)*